# Derivative of infimum in variational problem

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations

Let $\mathcal{E}(\phi,\alpha), \phi\in \mathcal{D}$ be a functional on some domain $\mathcal{D}$ that depends on a parameter $\alpha$.

In the expression

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha} \inf_{\phi \in D}\{\mathcal{E}(\phi,\alpha)\},$$

is there a way to justify exchanging the derivative and the infimum? What 
conditions does $\mathcal{E}$ and possibly the domain have to fulfill for that?

Comment: Were you able to make any headway with this? I'm dealing with a very similar problem :)

Comment: You can take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29867/derivatives-of-infimum) for an answer to this problem.