# Continuity of distance function without triangle inequality

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

We say that a continuous function $\rho : \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is a distance function if the following three conditions hold:

1.)  $\rho \geq 0$

2.) $\rho (z) =0$ iff $z=0$

3.) $\rho(cz)= |c| \cdot \rho(z)$ for all $c \in \mathbb{C}$ and $z \in \mathbb{C}^n$

Let $C \subset \mathbb{C}^n $ be closed. Define $d: \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ so that $d(z) = \inf_{w \in C} \rho(z -w)$. Show that $d$ is a continuous function.

Comment: What does $\rho(z - c)$ mean when $z \in \mathbb C^n$ and $c \in \mathbb C$?

Comment: It's $c \in C \subset \mathbb C^n$

Comment: op: That notation is bad to have $c$ used differently each time, I recommend the edit I submitted.

Comment: I rejected it because it's minor, and also your addition of the tag metric spaces is invalid - we specifically don't have the triangle inequality

Comment: This cannot be well-defined. Pick any $z_0\in\mathbb{C}^n\setminus \{0\}$ Then $\rho(iz_0)=i\rho(z_0)$ and both this and $\rho(z_0)$ cannot be real numbers.

Comment: I've edited it, apologizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from your conditions that $\rho(z)\geq a|z|$ with $a>0$. Indeed, $\rho$ is continuous and positive away from $0$, so it must reach a positive minimum on the unit sphere of $\mathbb{C}^n$ by compactness, say $a$. Then by the last condition for $z\neq0$ we have $\rho(z)=|z|\rho(z/|z|)\geq a|z|$.

Having this we can replace $\inf_{w \in C}\rho(z-w)$ in the definition of $d(z)$ by $\inf_{w \in C_R}\rho(z-w)$, where $C_R$ is the intersection of $C$ with a closed ball of appropriately chosen radius $R$, without changing its values on $z$ from some ball $B_r(z_0)$ around any $z_0$. Indeed, if the value of $|w|$ is large, so is the value of $|z-w|\geq|w|-|z|\geq|w|-r$, and hence so is the value of $\rho(z-w)\geq a(|w|-r)$. Therefore, the values of $\rho(z-w)$ for large $w$ are uniformly large as long as $z\in B_r(z_0)$, and do not affect the infimum over $C$.

The point of this is that $C_R$ is closed and bounded now, i.e. compact, and $\rho(z-w)$ is jointly continuous on $B_r(z_0)\times C_R$. It is a general fact that the infimum of continuous family of continuous functions over a compact set is continuous, see a proof [here](http://williewong.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/continuity-of-the-infimum/) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20300/infimum-is-a-continuous-function-compact-set). Thus, $d$ is continuous at $z_0$, and $z_0$ was arbitrary.

Comment: Your solution is wonderful - thank you.