# Is $\inf$ of a differentiable function still differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-optimization, large-deviation-theory

I'm new on stackexchange, thanks for this fantastic platform!

Let's get to the point. Suppose we have a function $I(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}$, $I(x,y) \geq 0$, convex, and differentiable for $x \in X$ compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Is

$$I(\omega) := \inf_{x \in X \\ {y = \omega x}} I(x,y) ,$$

$\omega \in \mathbb{R}$, still differentiable?
Please, note that the function defined as $\tilde{I}(x,\omega) := I(x,\omega x)$ in general is not convex anymore.

Comment: Is it even true that it is continuous? You might need $D$ convex to ensure that. Maybe even bounded.

Comment: I think it is. Have a look at [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20300/infimum-is-a-continuous-function-compact-set/1378023#1378023)

Comment: That requires that $D=X\times Y$ where $Y$ is compact, so it doesn't apply to all $D.$

Comment: Right, I'm good also in considering that case. Let me edit the question. Thanks.